# Proguard к kotlin модулям в Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, jvm, proguard

Моя библиотека имеет вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Провожу обфускацию каждого модуля с модуля типа android все понятно

```
buildTypes {
        debug{
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro', getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
```

и proguard делает свое дело, а вот koltin модуль (а именно auth.domain) не поддается этому правилу и все его подключении после обфускации других модулей, выглядит так как и выглядит, как это исправить?

что пока есть

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin'
    id 'idea'
}

ext {
    groupId = 'org.mycompany'
    artifactId = "uu.domain"
}

apply from: rootProject.file('publishing.gradle')

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.0'
}
```

Comment: Если у вас модули разного типа, то и обфусцировать их надо по разному. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/obfuscated-jars-what-are-the-best-practices/18834

Comment: Посмотрел, но ничего из перечислено не раскрыло хорошу суть, нравиться вариант в jar прописать, но не пойму где указать proguard.pro файл